# Spring Cloud AWS - AmazonS3 client is always null

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, spring-cloud

I'm trying to implement a file upload to an Amazon S3 Bucket using the Spring Cloud project.

According to the documentation:

> "A com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.TransferManager can be easily
>   created in the application code and injected with the pre-configured
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3 client that is already created with
>   the Spring Cloud AWS resource loader configuration."

This sample code doesnt work though:

```
public class SimpleResourceLoadingBean {

@Autowired
private AmazonS3 amazonS3;

public void withTransferManager() {
    TransferManager transferManager = new TransferManager(this.amazonS3);
    transferManager.upload("myBucket","filename",new File("someFile"));
}
```

}

The amazonS3 variable is always null.

My spring context config is as follows:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xmlns:aws-context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context" 
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/spring-cloud-aws-context.xsd">

<aws-context:context-credentials>
 <aws-context:simple-credentials access-key="KEY" secret-key="SECRET" />
</aws-context:context-credentials>

<aws-context:context-region region="eu-central-1"/>

<aws-context:context-resource-loader/>

<bean id="awsTransferManager" class="mytest.cloud.aws.AwsTransferManager" />
```

I'm using this class for testing:

```
public class AwsTransferManager {

@Autowired
private AmazonS3 amazonS3;

public void upload() throws AmazonServiceException, AmazonClientException, InterruptedException {
    TransferManager tx = new TransferManager(amazonS3);
    System.out.println(amazonS3); //always null
}
```

The test:

```
@Test
public void awsTest() throws Exception {
    ApplicationContext cxt = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/spring/spring-context.xml");
    AwsTransferManager manager = (AwsTransferManager)getContext().getBean("awsTransferManager");
    manager.upload();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out, I was missing the

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

part in my spring config.